# help on bisect usage

Tags: python

Can anyone explain how to use the [bpy.ops.mesh.bisect](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20mesh%20bisect#bpy.ops.mesh.bisect) operator.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(plane_co=(0, 0, 0), plane_no=(0, 0, 1.0), use_fill=False, clear_inner=False, clear_outer=False, threshold=0.0001, xstart=100, xend=101, ystart=100, yend=101, cursor=1002)
```

I undertand how everything works except for the 5 last fields (xstart, xend, ystart, yend and cursor).

So far, I was able to cut anything in any plane, but I want to use a semiplane not an entire plane.

ok it may be possible to do it with bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d, but my version of blender is 2.77 and unless i am doing something really wrong, it does not esem to have the view3d_utils.

is there any other way, even may be do it by myself all the calculations?
i know a lot of 3d and math so i feel able just, need to know where to get the data i need from.

by now i managed to set my view apropiately to have the data i want (for example i set it from left, and ortho instead of perspective so, it will not be messed up.

and i found a 3dpoint to camera, but that does it to camera not to a viewport, and in camera its distorted

Comment: The operator is used in the 3d viewport region [bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html?highlight=#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d) is a method that returns the object location as a 2d view location which the operator uses.  Generally from x,y mouse coords.

Comment: that can really be what i need, truly thanks, if i manage to get the border of my plane in 2d coordinates i think I will be able to solve it.
will test now. and if i can make it i post how to solve it.

Comment: Missed this comment till now, if you want to notify me, when I'm not the original poster,  put @batFINGER in your comment, and it will appear in my inbox.